# MySQL lag/lead function?

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate the difference between a users start time and stop time from previous session..

Table contains: user numeric, start/stop unix timestamp. It is sorted after both user AND start

```
user  start   stop
1    150000 150010
1    160011 160050
1    160100 160200
2    150011 150023
2    155001 155055
2    160001 160500
3    159001 159550
```

Im expecting the result to look like:

```
user start   stop  diff
1   150000 150010  160011-150010=10001
1   160011 160050  160100-160050
1   160100 160200  0 (new user on next row)
2   150011 150023  155001-150023
2   155001 155055  160001-155055
2   160001 160500  0 (new user on next row)
3   159001 159550  and so on..
```

Is it possible to do this, if so, how?

Comment: I would bet quite a big amount of beer that the business logic is flawed here. Why wouldn't the user have a time difference just because there is another user in the next row? Also, can we be sure that the table is ordered by the user id and by start date?

Comment: I haven't been able to create anything usefull.


Forgot to write, but yes the table is sorted after user AND start! I'm only looking for users difference, not the difference between users!

Åke

Comment: If I understand your data correctly then the difference in every row is the time difference of the same user. No other users are involved. Especially since their time intervals overlap in some cases.

Comment: Exactly! Like I said above, data is sorted after both user and start. So for the example above, user 1 only have 3 sessions, user 2 only have 3 session in the table..

Comment: Just FYI, Ake and @ytg, data is not sorted in a relational DBMS. Never. That's what the `ORDER BY` clause is for. If you don't specify it, you can not be sure, that the data is returned in the same order every time you execute your query.

Comment: MariaDB 10.2 and MySQL 8.0.1 have "windowing" functions that might work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is better done on application level, but just for fun, here it is on database level:

```
select `user`, `start`, `stop`, diff from (
    select
    t.*
    , if(@prev_user = `user`, (`stop` - @prev) * -1, 0) as diff
    , @prev := `start`
    , @prev_user := `user`
    from
    t
    , (select @prev := null, @prev_user := null) var_init
    order by `user`, `start` desc
) sq
order by `user`, `start`
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ca3b/9/0)

Note, that there are no lag/lead functions in MySQL. All you can do, is to use variables. The `SELECT` clause gets processed one line at a time. So you can assign the value of the current row in the last lines of the `SELECT` clause and therefore use this variable as the value of "the previous row" in the first lines of the `SELECT` clause.
Also note, that the `ORDER BY` is very important. A table is not sorted. Data in a relational DBMS is not sorted unless you specify an order with the `ORDER BY` clause.

- read more about using variables in queries [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html)

EDIT:

Change it to

```
UPDATE inactivitytmp
JOIN (
SELECT
inactivitytmp.*
, if(@prev_user_id = `user_id`, (`end_ts` - @prev) * -1, 0) as diff2
, @prev := `start_ts`
, @prev_user_id := `user_id`
FROM
inactivitytmp
, (SELECT @prev := null, @prev_user_id := null) var_init
ORDER BY `user_id`, `start_ts` DESC
) query_alias
ON inactivitytmp.user_id=query_alias.user_id AND inactivitytmp.start_ts=q uery_alias.start_ts AND inactivitytmp.end_ts=query_alias.end_ts
SET inactivitytmp.diff=query_alias.diff2;
```