# SQL - Calculate the difference in number of orders by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, self-join

I am working on the orders table provided by this [site](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_try_sql.php), it has its own editor where you can test your SQL statements.

The order table looks like this

| order_id | customer_id | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7000 | 2016/04/18 |
| 2 | 5000 | 2016/04/18 |
| 3 | 8000 | 2016/04/19 |
| 4 | 4000 | 2016/04/20 |
| 5 | NULL | 2016/05/01 |

I want to get the difference in the number of orders for subsequent months.

To elaborate, the number of orders each month would be like this

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(order_date) AS Month,
    COUNT(MONTH(order_date)) AS Total_Orders
FROM
    orders
GROUP BY
    MONTH(order_date)
```

Result:

| Month | Total_Orders |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 |

Now my goal is to get the difference in subsequent months which would be

| Month | Total_Orders | Total_Orders_Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 4 - Null = Null |
| 5 | 1 | 1 - 4 = -3 |

My strategy was to self-join following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32346847/1831518)

This was my attempt

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(a.order_date),
    COUNT(MONTH(a.order_date)),
    COUNT(MONTH(b.order_date)) - COUNT(MONTH(a.order_date)) AS prev,
    MONTH(b.order_date)
FROM 
    orders a
LEFT JOIN 
    orders b ON MONTH(a.order_date) = MONTH(b.order_date) - 1
GROUP BY
    MONTH(a.order_date)
```

However, the result was just zeros (as shown below) which suggests that I am just subtracting from the same value rather than from the previous month (or subtracting from a null value)

| MONTH(a.order_date) | COUNT(MONTH(a.order_date)) | prev | MONTH(b.order_date) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 0 | NULL |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | NULL |

Do you have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your task lends itself well to window function and `lag()`

Comment: @Stu there's an assumption (related to my task) that window functions are not available. This basically means that there's a solution that does not depend on lag

Comment: Ah - ok well I just posted an example that uses `lag` - sorry, you didn't provide a list of syntax not to be used lol ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - get summary of differences vs previous month](/q/63737197/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `LAG` window function in your SELECT statement.

> LAG provides access to a row at a given physical offset that comes
> before the current row.

So, this is what you need:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(order_date)           as Month,
    COUNT(MONTH(order_date))    as Total_Orders,
    COUNT(MONTH(order_date)) - (LAG (COUNT(MONTH(order_date))) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) AS Total_Orders_Diff
FROM orders
GROUP BY MONTH(order_date);
```

Here in an example on the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ed75/1

Solution without using `LAG` window function:

```
WITH InitCTE AS
(
    SELECT MONTH(order_date) AS Month,
           COUNT(MONTH(order_date)) AS Total_Orders
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY MONTH(order_date)
)
SELECT InitCTE.Month, InitCTE.Total_Orders, R.Total_Orders_Diff
FROM InitCTE
      OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 InitCTE.Total_Orders - CompareCTE.Total_Orders AS Total_Orders_Diff
                   FROM InitCTE AS CompareCTE
                   WHERE CompareCTE.Month < InitCTE.Month) R;
```

---

Comment: there's an assumption (related to my task) that window functions are not available. This basically means that there's a solution that does not depend on lag. Also your statement results in a parsing error "SyntaxError: Parse error on line 4:
...MONTH(order_date))) OVER (ORDER BY (SELE"

Comment: @AbdelrahmanShoman this solution will work if you execute directly on the database, it will not work if you try on the attached website because it doesn't support window functions. I have updated my answer and attached SQL Fiddle link.

Comment: Maeisc, I see, thanks. However, I am working under the assumption I can't use window functions (this related to my task). That's why I am assuming the solution would be using joins

Comment: @AbdelrahmanShoman I have written a statement for you without using window functions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should give you what you want - disclaimer, untested!

```
select *, Total_Orders - lag(Total_orders,1) over(order by Month) as Total_Orders_Diff
from (
 select Month(order_date) as Month, Count(*) as Total_Orders
 From orders
 Group by Month(order_date)
)o
```

Comment: this will get me a syntax error "SyntaxError: Parse error on line 1:
...lag(Total_orders,1) over(order by Month)". You can try it here: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_try_sql.php

Comment: @AbdelrahmanShoman the same query will return correct results if you try on the SQL Fiddle link I attached in my answer.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanShoman It looks like that does not support SQLServer syntax in that scenario - the `lag` statement above is fine, I've just checked it in SQLServer.