# Subtracting two values in a column using sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008-r2, oracle10g

I want to display the subtraction of two values from two different rows using a SQL query.

This is the table structure:

```
id | Value|
-----------
1  | 20 | 
2  | 30 | 
3  | 50 |
4  | 70 |
5  | 100 |
```

Output should be as follows.

```
id | Value| Difference |
------------------------
1  | 20 | Null |
2  | 30 | 10 |
3  | 50 | 20 |
4  | 70 | 20 |
5  | 100 | 30 |
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed that `ID` field represents a continuous sequence of numbers? Is `ID` of the preceding row always less by **one** than the current row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for `SQL Server` and I expect the ones for Oracle and MySQL to be very similar.

**Note:** `Id`s do not have to be contigous, but I use them for ordering the results.

**Setup:**

```
-- drop table dbo.testVals
CREATE TABLE dbo.testVals (
    Id INT,
    Value INT
)
GO

-- truncate table dbo.testVals 
INSERT INTO dbo.testVals (Id, Value)
VALUES (1, 20),  (2, 30),  (3, 50), (4, 70), (5, 100)
GO
```

**SQL Server 2008 R2 solution:**

```
;WITH cte as (
    SELECT Id, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNo
    FROM dbo.testVals
)
SELECT r1.Id, r1.Value, r1.Value - r2.Value 
FROM cte r1 
    LEFT JOIN cte r2 ON r2.RowNo = r1.RowNo - 1
GO
```

**SQL Server 2012 solution:** (we have LAG and LEAD functions there)

```
SELECT Id, Value, Value - LAG(Value, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY Id)
FROM dbo.testVals
GO
```

Oracle has LAG and [LEAD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm) functions. MySQL does [not seem to have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556063/mysql-lag-lead-function) them, so you should use something similar to the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.value,
CASE t2.value WHEN NULL THEN NULL ELSE (t1.value - t2.value) END AS Difference
FROM mytable t1 LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.id = (t2.id + 1) ORDER BY t1.id
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a70df/3)

Comment: What if there is a gap in the ID ? say 7 after 5?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
SELECT id, VALUE, (VALUE - previousValue) AS difference  FROM (
SELECT id, VALUE, @prevValue previousValue , @prevValue := `VALUE` FROM `mytable`
JOIN (SELECT @prevValue := NULL) a
ORDER BY id ) b;
```

See the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a86b/1)