# How to select mysql records with n minutes maximum difference in datetime column?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, mariadb, innodb

I want to show MySQL records  with maximum 3 minutes difference in datetime column grouped by LoginID column

example :

```
LoginID|  LogTime
-------+---------------------
435678 |   2018-03-29 08:26:02
435678 |   2018-03-29 08:27:12
435678 |   2018-03-29 08:27:32
435678 |   2018-03-29 08:28:06
```

Comment: Please share the code you wrote that did not produce the desired output.

Comment: Hmm...this is easier in other databases.  Actually, what version of MySQL?  version 8.0 has lag/lead functionality.  Failing that, you are stuck to harsher work arounds.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556063/mysql-lag-lead-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will group them by loginId and get the difference between max logintime and min logintime. Then join them to the table using loginid but filter the timediff to less tham 3 minutes.

```
Select tbl.*
From tbl 
Join (
Select loginId,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, min(logtime),max(logtime))
  As timediff
From tbl
Group by loginId ) tab
  On tbl.loginId = tab.loginId
  Where tab.timediff < 3
  Order by 1, 2
```